# redux-from initialValues set not working for Select Option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-form

i have an update form using redux-form, form value initiate using initialValues

example : `<DataEdit initialValues={ Data }/>`

and using data in DataEdit page like

```
    <Field
    name="Data.taxTitle"
    component={renderField}
    type="text"
    validate={required}
    label ="Title"
  />
```

above part is working fine, and my Select option filed is look likes

```
 <Field name="Data.gender" component={renderSelectField} >
    <option value="male">male</option>
    <option value="female">female</option>
  </Field>

 {genderValue ==='male' ?
   (<div> 
     <Field
      name="Data.name"
      component={renderField}
      type="text"
      validate={required}
      label ="name"
     /> 
   </div>) : null

 {genderValue ==='female' ?
   (<div> 
     <Field
      name="Data.name"
      component={renderField}
      type="text"
      validate={required}
      label ="name"
     /> 
   </div>) : null
```

the above part is working fine in insert, but when comes to the update Select have value(it's shows what i save in insert, male or female) but not shows another filed called `{genderValue ==='male' or {genderValue ==='female'`

genderValue from [Selecting Form Values Example](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/selectingformvalues/)

```
DataEdit = connect(state => {
   const genderValue = selector(state, 'gender');
  return {
    genderValue
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gender field is called `Data.gender` while in the selector you are using `gender`

On a side note there is no need to duplicate the Field Data.name, you can unify the condition with genderValue === 'male' || genderValue === 'female'